# Plotly histogram displays a range of values in one bar when there is a realy big number of observations

Tags: r, plotly

I observed that plotly displays a range of values when mouse hovering over one bar instead of a single value when we have a very large dataset. How can this be fixed? In the example below I would like to see the number of 0.34 and of the range 0.34-0.36.

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(x = ~rnorm(500000), type = "histogram")
p
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(x = ~rnorm(500), type = "histogram", hoverinfo = 'y')
p
```